# Calculated Column Question

Tags: 2010, column

I currently have a list with the Column - "**Level**"
This column is a choice column with the choices: "Novice" and "Beginner"

I'm creating a calculated column called "**Score**"
I want this column to produce "1" if "Level" is Novice, and "2" if "Level" is Beginner

My Code I've been trying to use is..

```
=IF([Level]="Novice",[Score]="1"),
IF([Level]="Beginner",[Score]="2")
```

Can someone help clear up my confusions? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can use above mentioned options also. But if there is no value selected for Level column, the score column returns some unexpected result.

We have three options totally to achieve this,

1. `=IF(Level="Novice","1","2")`

   - If the Level column has empty value, then the score always **2**
2. `=(IF([Level]="Novice","1", IF([Level]="Beginner","2")))`

   - If the Level column is empty, the score value is **No**
3. `=(IF([Level]="Novice","1", IF([Level]="Beginner","2","")))`

   - If the level column is empty, the score value also empty.
   - If the level column is Novice, the score value is **1**
   - If the level column is Beginner, the score value is **2**

Choose one from the above based on your choice / requirment

Comment: Great answer! I took the easy way out with my response.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `=(IF([Level]="Novice","1", IF([Level]="Beginner","2")))`

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE you must have misunderstood the question, as this provides the question. OP tried different options are is asking for help with the calculation formula.

Answer (score 0):

If Novice and Beginner are your only choices you can use `=IF(Level="Novice","1","2")`

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE How does my post not provide an answer to the question?